# How to print rows information from two dimensional array in Perl?

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array

I have the following two dimensional array (file.txt):

```
Code  Element  Repetitions
AL     Train       23
BM      Car        30
CN      Bike       44
```

From an input (Code) given by the user, I want to extract the 
corresponding Element information.

```
Example input: BM   
Example output:Car
```

I tried with this code but I do not know how to compare the input name with array content. Thank you a lot

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;

print("Type code: ");  
my $code = <STDIN>;
chomp($code);

my @content;

if(!open(TABLET, "file.txt")){              
die "Unable to open the file\n";
}
while(<TABLET>){
    chomp;
  push @content, [split / /];
}

foreach my $row ($content) {
    if ($content{$code}) {                                    
        print "$content{$code}\n";
    }
}

close(TABLET);
```

Comment: `... if ($row->[0] eq $code) { print $row->[1]; }...` or instead of an array you could use a hash with the code as key, if the code is unique in the file. How you wrote it, `$content{$code}`, you're probably after that.

Comment: Kinda off-topic but please try to always `use strict`in your Perl scripts! Just makes sure that in the future any "major" mistake is pointed out when executing the script beforehand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems here. And they can mostly be found by adding `use strict` to your code. The vast majority of experienced Perl programmers will always start their programs with:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

as these additions will find a huge number of common mistakes that programmers are prone to make.

The first problem can't be found like that. It seems to be a typo. You split your input using `split /;+/` but your input file seems to be delimited by whitespace. So change `split /;+/` to just `split`.

Now let's add `use strict` to your code and see what happens.

```
$ perl 2d
Global symbol "$content" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $content"?) at 2d line 20.
Global symbol "%content" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my %content"?) at 2d line 21.
Global symbol "%content" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my %content"?) at 2d line 22.
Execution of 2d aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Although there are three errors listed here, the second and third ones are both the same. But let's start with the first. Line 20 in my program is:

```
foreach my $row ($content) {
```

But what's that `$content` variable? You don't use that anywhere else. I suspect it's a typo for `@content`. Let's change that and try again.

```
$ perl 2d
Global symbol "%content" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my %content"?) at 2d line 21.
Global symbol "%content" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my %content"?) at 2d line 22.
Execution of 2d aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Ok. That fixed the first problem, but I guess we now have to look at the repeated error. This is generated by lines 21 and 22, which look like this:

```
    if ($content{$code}) {
        print "$content{$code}\n";
```

Obviously, there's no mention of `%content` on either of those lines - so what's the problem?

Well, the problem is that `%content` is mentioned on both of those lines, but it's disguised as `$content{$code}` in both cases. You have an array called `@content` and you'd look up values in that array using syntax like `$content[0]`. The face that you're using `{...}` instead of `[...]` means that you're looking in `%content`, not `@content` (in Perl you're allowed to have an array and a hash - and also a scalar - all with the same name, which is always a terrible idea!)

But we can't just change `$content{$code}` to `$content[$code]` because `$code` is string ("BM") and array indexes are integers. I we need to rethink this from scratch and actually store the data in `%content`, not `@content`. And, actually, I think that makes the code simpler.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

print("Type code: ");
my $code = <STDIN>;
chomp($code);

my %content;

if  (!open(TABLET, "file.txt")){
  die "Unable to open the file\n";
}

while(<TABLET>){
  chomp;
  my @record = split;
  $content{$record[0]} = \@record;
}

if (exists $content{$code}) {
  print "$content{$code}[1]\n";
} else {
  print "$code is not a valid code\n";
}

close(TABLET);
```

We can clean that up a bit (for example, by using lexical filehandles and the three-arg version of `open()`) to get this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

print("Type code: ");
chomp( my $code = <STDIN> );

my %content;

open my $tablet_fh, '<', 'file.txt'
  or die "Unable to open the file\n";

while(<$tablet_fh>){
  chomp;
  my @record = split;
  $content{$record[0]} = \@record;
}

if (exists $content{$code}) {
  print "$content{$code}[1]\n";
} else {
  print "$code is not a valid code\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.. Now it is working. I will fix the typo mentioned (use strict, split, $content)